# Bootstrap, how to do deal with the large array of resolution included in the LARGE (lg) definition?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I've a webapp built using bootstrap grid system.
I've used medium and large column definition to adapt the design to medium and large screen (not the same number of column ...).

However i'm having problem with the wide scope of resolution included in the bootstrap LARGE definition.

On some laptop, that are almost to medium def but are still considered as large .
I would want those to be considered as medium for display.

Is there a way to overload bootstrap definition of large and medium screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

You can do it by tweaking directly your css file, but MUCH easier to use the customizer.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

On this site scroll down until `Media queries breakpoints` there you can change the values.

Good luck.

Comment: yes i've found that by replacing in the .css file 1200PX everywhere by 1300px it worked.